# how to run code openCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am beginner in programming  i show this class

http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2014/03/06/people-detection-in-processing-with-opencv/
& i want to run it in net beans but main method is missed & some errors appears like can not find PImage  also  , size ,background
can you help me how to run it & what should classes must be have.

```
PImage small;
HOGDescriptor hog;

byte [] bArray;
int [] iArray;
int pixCnt1, pixCnt2;
int w, h;
float ratio;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  ratio = 0.5;
  w = int(width*ratio);
  h = int(height*ratio);

  background(0);
  // Define and initialise the default capture device.
  cap = new Capture(this, width, height);
  cap.start();

  // Load the OpenCV native library.
  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
  println(Core.VERSION);


  pixCnt1 = w*h*4;
  pixCnt2 = w*h;

  bArray = new byte[pixCnt1];
  iArray = new int[pixCnt2];

  small = createImage(w, h, ARGB);
  hog = new HOGDescriptor();
  hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector());
  noFill();
  stroke(255, 255, 0);
}

void draw() {
  if (cap.available()) {
    cap.read();
  } 
  else {
    return;
  }
  image(cap, 0, 0);
```

Comment: "I am beginner in programming" - maybe then - avoid opaque (and badly maintained) 3rd party frameworks like processing ? if you want to use opencv on android, rather stick to the official opencv4android sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy everything from that page including the import, i'm thinking those objects you're trying to create are from the things that were suppose to be imported so that might solve your problem with that.